# Concatenate a variable and a string in Smarty in order to include a file

Tags: php, include, concatenation, smarty, prestashop

In a tpl file, i need to include a file dynamically, with a concatenation of a string and a variable.

This work (no concatenation) :

```
{include file="catalog/_partials/faq-86.tpl"}
```

Then, i would like to replace "86" by a variable (the product id).

Here is what i’ve tried (based on other answers on stackoverflow , on smarty forum or smarty documentation):

1)

```
{include file="catalog/_partials/{$product.name}.tpl"}
```

2)

```
{assign var="id_pr" value="85"}
{include file="catalog/_partials/.$id_pr.tpl"}
```

3)

```
{assign var="id_pr" value="85"}
{include file="catalog/_partials/$id_pr.tpl"}
```

4)

```
{include file="{'catalog/_partials/'}{$product.name}{'.tpl'}"}
```

5)

```
{assign var='url' value="{'catalog/_partials/'}{$product.name}{'.tpl'}"} 
{include file=$url}
```

Here is the smarty error :

> Syntax error in template "templates/catalog/product.tpl" on line 273
>   "{include file="catalog/_partials/{$product.name}.tpl"}" variable
>   template file names not allow within {block} tags

So my, question, is it possible to concatenate a variable and a string in order to include a file ?

I know it is not the best approach but for templating purpose, I need to quickly load different tpl files on different product page.

I think it is possible since this condition is working (no concatenation but the file is included dynamically)  :

```
{if $product.id === 85}

    {include file="catalog/_partials/faq-85.tpl"}

{elseif $product.id === 86}

    {include file="catalog/_partials/faq-86.tpl"}

{/if}
```

Comment: which version of smarty you are using? I'm use smarty3 in some project and the first style working normally for me, so you {block} tag ?

Comment: I don’t know, i’m using Prestashop 1.7 (latest version) so i guess it is the latest smarty version but i need to check this.

Comment: looks like that prestashop is using a forked version of smarty , https://github.com/PrestaShop/smarty

Comment: Ok, i need to check this. I thought it was the Smarty version which do not allow to concatenate a template var because i understand i should not do this. But it’s php, it should be possible…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the cat function like this:

```
{assign var='url' value="catalog/_partials/"|cat:$product.name|cat:".tpl"} 
{include file=$url}
```

Looks like you are using Prestashop 1.7 that has smarty version 3.1.19 and as i found in their forums (and tested) you have to edit the file `/vendor/prestashop/smarty/Smarty.class.php`, look for `inheritance_merge_compiled_includes` and set to `false`. Then delete all the cache templates (delete the folder `/app/cache/dev` and `/app/cache/prod`) and it should work inside the block element. It worked in my test.

Comment: Yes, i’ve seen `cat` in Smarty documentation. I’ve tried your code but i still have a smarty error : `{include file=$url}" variable template file names not allow within {block} tags`It should work, the syntax is correct.

Comment: If i display `$url` in template with `{$url}`, the result is correct : `catalog/_partials/faq-85.tpl`so the concatenation is working. Your solution is ok. But i still can’t use this variable to include a file.

Comment: and if it's not in a {block} it works. i just tested in another version and it includes a file. will try again inside a {block}

Comment: you’re right, the code outside a `{block}`is working, i have no more smarty error But i need to include this file inside the `{block name='content'}`in prestashop template file. I’ll check if i can do something outside a block.

Comment: I’m totally impressed by your answer, i’ve spent a couple of hours on this basic issue and didn’t found any infos about this. You find the tip on prestshop forum ?

Comment: Thanks. No, it was on the smarty forum. Others had the same issue on previous versions. Luckly prestashop 1.7 uses a version were this was implemented, or you would have to update it.